# Different users, middleware Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I'm trying to use different user levels at my system. I have at data base my users and their levels (master, portais, chaves, etc)

So, what I want is different routes for each user, so each one will access just a part of the system.

I can easily check in each page of the system his AUTH and dont show to him the page if he is logged in a account witch he shouldn't see that page. BUT, there's a easy way to do it with middleware / Routes no?!

I tried something like this on my routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'Master'], function()
{
    Route::any('/vendedor/produtos/removeProduto', 'AjaxController@vendedorRemoveProduto');
    Route::any('/vendedor/produtos/editaPrecoProduto', 'AjaxController@editaPrecoProduto');
    Route::any('/vendedor/produtos/alterarestadoproduto', 'AjaxController@alterarestadoumproduto');
    Route::any('/vendedor/produtos/listaProdutos', 'AjaxController@listaProdutos');
    Route::any('/vendedor/produtos/adicionaProdutoCliente', 'AjaxController@adicionaProdutoCliente');
    Route::any('/', 'DashboardController@home'); });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'portais'], function()
{
    Route::any('/cadastrarobjedu/criartema', 'AjaxController@criartemaobjedu');
    Route::any('/cadastrarobjedu/cadastrar', 'AjaxController@cadastraobjedu');
    Route::any('/cadastrarobjedu', 'DashboardController@cadastrarobjedu');
    Route::any('/listarobjedu', 'DashboardController@listarobjedu');
    Route::any('/editarobjeto/{id}', 'DashboardController@editarobjeto');
    Route::any('/apagarobjeto/{id}', 'AjaxController@apagarobjeto');
    Route::any('/', 'DashboardController@home'); });
```

But this didn't work, hgive me a error saying the "MASTER" class dosen't exist. I have change anything more?

Comment: Have you implemented Master class? If not, then no wonder it doesn't exist :)

Comment: What version lf Laravel are you using? 5.0 or 5.1?

Comment: 5.0 guys.

No I didn't, in fact I'm little lost on how and where implement the class.

Is at the same folder of the Authentication.php?

APP->Http->controllers->Middleware

Is there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a middleware that would check if current user has given level.

**Laravel 5.0**

```
//app/Http/Kernel.php - register middleware classes
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'levelMaster'  => 'App\Http\Middleware\LevelMasterMiddleware',
    'levelPortais' => 'App\Http\Middleware\LevelPortaisMiddleware'
];

//app/Http/Middleware/LevelMiddleware.php - base middleware class that checks if user has level stored in $level;
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App;
use Auth;

abstract class LevelMiddleware
{   
    protected $level;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->level !== $this->level) {
            return App::abort(Auth::check() ? 403 : 401, Auth::check() ? 'Forbidden' : 'Unauthorized');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

//app/Kernel/Middleware/LevelMasterMiddleware.php - checks if user has level Master
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class LevelMasterMiddleware extends LevelMiddleware
{   
    protected $level = 'master';
}

//app/Kernel/Middleware/LevelPortaisMiddleware.php - checks if user has level Portais
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class LevelPortaisMiddleware extends LevelMiddleware
{   
    protected $level = 'portais';
}

//config/routes.php - configure routes for different levels
Route::group(['middleware' => 'levelMaster'], function()    
{
    //here add routes for users with level=master
}

Route::group(['middleware' => 'levelPortais'], function()    
{
    //here add routes for users with level=portais
}
```

**Laravel 5.1**

The latest version of Laravel introduces middleware parameters which lets simplify the above code a bit, as only one middleware class will be needed:

```
//app/Http/Kernel.php - register middleware class
protected $routeMiddleware = ['level' => 'App\Http\Middleware\LevelMiddleware'];

//app/Http/Middleware/LevelMiddleware.php - check if current user has given level
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App;
use Auth;

class LevelMiddleware
{    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $level)
    {
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->level !== $level) {
            return App::abort(Auth::check() ? 403 : 401, Auth::check() ? 'Forbidden' : 'Unauthorized');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

//config/routes.php - configure routes for different levels and pass level as middleware parameter
Route::group(['middleware' => 'level:master'], function()    
{
    //here add routes for users with level=master
}

Route::group(['middleware' => 'level:portais'], function()    
{
    //here add routes for users with level=portais
}
```

Comment: Tnx dude, I'll try it now. :D

Comment: I dont have the LevelMiddleware.php here... Have to create it right?

Sry but I'm really new on laravel :D

Comment: HAHAHHAH now I understand, I have to create each one of the levels.php right?

Comment: Yes, you need to add middleware classes

Comment: So I'll create 4 new PHP files:


LevelMasterMiddleware.php


LevelChavesMiddleware.php


LevelObjetosMiddleware.php


LevelPortaisMiddleware.php


And I change the abstract class name in each one right?

Comment: You set $level variable to whatever level you want to check. All those classes need to extend the base LevelMiddleware that contains the logic

Comment: Ok, almost work, I'm getting forbiden for any login:

in Application.php line 880
at Application->abort('403', 'Forbidden') in Facade.php line 213
at Facade::__callStatic('abort', array('403', 'Forbidden')) in LevelMiddleware.php line 14
at App::abort('403', 'Forbidden') in LevelMiddleware.php line 14

Comment: and...? You wanted to get 403 if users do not have a proper level.

Comment: Yes, but I'm logging with an account with the proper level :D

in fact I tried with accounts of each level, none work :(

Comment: If something else should happen if user doesn't have the proper level you'll need to replace App::abort part with some other logic

Comment: Do "dd(Auth::user()->level);"  (or whatever you use to store the user level) at the beginning of handle function in the middleware and paste the output

Comment: This part: protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'levelMaster'  => 'App\Http\Middleware\LevelMasterMiddleware',
    'levelPortais' => 'App\Http\Middleware\LevelPortaisMiddleware'
];

shouldn't use "master, "portais" instead "levelMaster"...?

Comment: The thing is:

dd(Auth::user()->level); = 'chaves'

dd($this->level) = "portais"

so they are different, so I got the 403...

Comment: It means you opened a route for level portais with user that has level chaves, correct? So that is why middleware returns 403. Isnt it what you needed? Maybe i misunderstood your intentions

Comment: Nops, what I need is:

masters will have X routes (all the pages)

portais will have Y routes (some pages just for who logged in with portais level)

Chaves will have Z routes

etc etc...

Comment: Then implementacji that logic and rolę hierarchy in the middleware.

Comment: I did, But i didn't find where I'm doing something wrong. For me looks everything fine. (Sry for take too long to answer)

Comment: Yeah, I'll put it on my drive, second please.